# Custom URLs in Custom Search Results

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, search

I need your help with Custom URLs in Custom Search Results (Wordpress).

I have this URL http://domain.com/?s=&categories=489&locations=310 which get me search results.

I can replace IDs with Category and Location "Slug" to look like this

http://domain.com/find/category-in-location/ and get same search results as with old URL address.

Note: I use Yoast SEO plugin in Wordpress.

Thank you for your help and cooperation.

Answer (score 4):

You can get close to what you want by using the `template_redirect` hook.

```
function my_custom_search_url_rewrite() {
  if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
    exit();
  } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_custom_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Then you can use a URL like `http://domain.com/search/category+location/`.

If you then want to change `search` into `find` you could use the `search_rewrite_rules` filter like this.

```
function my_custom_search_url( $search_rewrite ) {
  if( !is_array( $search_rewrite ) ) { 
    return $search_rewrite;
  }

  $new_array = array();

  foreach( $search_rewrite as $pattern => $s_query_string ) {
    $new_array[ str_replace( 'search/', 'find/', $pattern ) ] = $s_query_string;
  }

  $search_rewrite = $new_array;

  unset( $new_array );

  return $search_rewrite;
}
add_filter("search_rewrite_rules", "my_custom_search_url");
```

Then you can use a URL like `http://domain.com/find/category+location/`.

**Note:** Remember to flush or re-save your permalinks.

I'm sure, with some more tinkering, you could get a bit closer to what you asked for but this is as close I've got so far.

**EDIT:**
Sorry forgot to mention... if you use the function for the `search_rewrite_rules` filter you'll need to change the `my_custom_url_rewrite` function to this.

```
function my_custom_search_url_rewrite() {
  if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( "/find/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
    exit();
  } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_custom_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Dear Mr. James Barrett, please see my next post. Thank you for your help and cooperation.